# How do I append css to a table row based on id after the Document has loaded

Tags: jquery

Using Jquery, how would I give css to table rows, after the document has already loaded.

The problem here is that they are table rows, and I need the table rows to be side by side! I do not have access to change those tr tags, and I have to use id.

for example:

```
<table>
   <tr id="left"></tr>
   <tr id="right"></tr>
</table>
```

EDIT

I apologize everyone. they are Table Data's

```
<tr>
    <td id="left"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="right"></td>
</tr>
```

Update EDIT 2

The TD that I need is actually the 5th occurence but i need it in the utmost left of the dom.

```
<tr>
    <td id="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="2"></td>
</tr>
#except I need the id 2 in the farthest uppermost left
```

Using float: left; on id 2, and using clear or anything else on Id 1 did not work

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about doing something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $("#left").css("float", "left");
    $("#right").css("float", "left");
});
```

Keep in mind you'll need to clear your floats after you're done with each set.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp  - Usually I'll use a clear after a set of objects that I want to all float against each other. This will keep your floated elements from butting against any other page elements. An example would be to set "clear:both" on a block element after your floating elements, I'll usually create a div just for this purpose. Then the rest of my page is unaffected by the floated objects.

Comment: I apologize, I updated question. Is it still possible?

Comment: I feel like we're going about this in the wrong way. Is there any way you can give us more background knowledge on your task? Maybe we can come up with a different kind of solution besides using jquery to float table cells. Also please note what kind of environment you're working in, and what constraints you have. You mentioned not having access to the HTML, or rather the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting the CSS display on the parent row to "table-cell".

```
$(function(){
    $("#left").parent().css("display", "table-cell");
    $("#right").parent().css("display", "table-cell");
});
```

Comment: ...Updated answer @christopherclark

Comment: Okay the problem now is that the table data i need at the utmost farthest left is at the bottom because its the 5th table data, I will update my question